# No Such Method error while using implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10))

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, implicitwait, seleniumwaits

`This error is coming when I removed deprecated implicit wait to latest one.

Please any one provide me a solution to resolve this.

To launch a browser successfully`

[Issue is that No such method error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1m77.png)
Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$Timeouts org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$Timeouts.implicitlyWait(java.time.Duration)'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhntO.png)